# Do an OR in Switch-Case in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How would you do this in C++? For example I'm trying to trigger a program exit both if the user presses ESC or 'q' or 'Q'.

I've tried looking for it, but I found no syntax for it in C++. I know how to do it with if-else, but is it possible with switch - case? Of course I can just make a function and call it from two separate case, but is there a way to do it just by combined case statement?

For example that's what I'm looking for (of course not working):

```
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch( key )
    {
        case ( 27 || 'q' || 'Q' ):
            exit( 0 );
            break;

        case 'a': ...

                case 'b': ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your `switch` statement by using `tolower` or `toupper` first.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Cases fall through without a break:

```
case  27: //could be 27
case 'q': //could be 27 or 'q'
case 'Q': //could be 27, 'q', or 'Q'
    exit(0);
    break;
```

Comment: Darn it I was totally at "break" when the new answer notification came up

Comment: And _ALWAYS_ put comments saying that the fallthrough is deliberate and why.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Good point. To other people it might look like you accidentally left out a break statement, and if you didn't, that could turn out less-than-pretty.

Comment: @MooingDuck clang has [`[[clang::fallthrough]]`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#clang__fallthrough), which might be interesting as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck Alternately it could introduce excessive commenting. I would not comment it personally. If someone doesn't understand why it is there, he would most likely not understand the software being developed and shouldn't be touching the code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just

```
switch(key){
 case 'a': case 'b':  
    /*code*/ 
    break;

    ...
```

Cases A and B will both execute the same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch( key )
    {
        case 027:
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            exit( 0 );
            break;

        case 'a': ...

        case 'b': ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful - `027` and `27` aren't the same.  The leading `0` in `027` is the prefix for an octal literal, so `027` != `27`.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax becomes

```
  void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
  {
      switch( key )
      {
          case  27:
          case 'q':
          case 'Q':
              exit( 0 );
              break;

         case 'a': ...

         case 'b': ...
      }
  }
```